# Recursive file walk only going one depth down

Tags: python

I am trying to create code for an assignment that can walk down a directory and return all files

I am having trouble with multilevel folders, such as

folder1 
---> folder2 
------->foo.txt

I have the following code

```
def find_larger(path, max_n_results=10):
    files = []
    print(path)
    path_files = os.listdir(path)
    for file in path_files:
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            files += find_larger(os.path.join(path, file))
        files.append(file)
    return files

print(find_larger('.'))
```

However, If I were to run that code I would get the following result

[folder1, folder2]

I have run through this is a debugger and the program is not detecting the second directory to actually be a directory.

How can I get the program to walk all the way through the directory.

Note, I am not allowed to user os.walk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.path.isdir()` takes a full path, you are only giving it the relative name. Create the path first, then test that:

```
def find_larger(path, max_n_results=10):
    files = []
    print(path)
    path_files = os.listdir(path)
    for file in path_files:
        subpath = os.path.join(path, file)
        if os.path.isdir(subpath):
            files += find_larger(subpath)
        files.append(subpath)
    return files
```

However, you are re-inventing a wheel here, just use the [`os.walk()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to list directory contents :

```
def find_larger(path, max_n_results=10):
    files = []
    print(path)
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        files += (os.join(dirpath, filename) for filename in filenames)
    return files
```